# Installing SQL Server 2014 using chef community cookbook (sql_server)

Tags: sql-server, chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I've had a look at the chef community cookbook for installing sql server and it appears that it's tailored for installing SQL express, but I can't seem to work out how to install a standard or developer edition.

The README on the GitHub page (https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/sql_server) says you can just point it to any installation package, however I can't see how you would do this for an ISO (or even the extracted contents of an ISO) given that there's no single EXE package on the ISO media.

Am I missing something obvious, or will I need to roll my own recipe for installing SQL from an ISO (or contents of ISO)?  Ideally I would like to host the installation media on a central package repository behind my firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

Customized cookbook is the best option for you use case. Like you said, host .ISO on central repo and create a cookbook that mounts the .ISO drive to run the installation. You should leverage that cookbook template and re-write that `windows_package` block in the `server.rb` to install using keyword '`source`' with path to the mounted installation files. However, this will be a major work (from past experience...) so if you have only one or two nodes that need to run the cookbook, go with Option 2.

Option 2:

If you have only one or two nodes that need to run the cookbook, I would suggest you to run the basic '`sql_server::server`' then upgrade to the version you want using the GUI with the PID product key.

Note that this process can be automated as well using Powershell script. If you are familiar with Powershell, you can automate it using `powershell_script` block.

Comment: Thanks, I really was hoping to follow the "always use a community cookbook" pattern - but it seems like the requirement to use a locally hosted ISO makes that an impossibility.  Option 1 seems good to me.

Answer (score 0):

ISOs are intended for DVD images but if you have an ISO shredder (search online for free tools) you'll see a setup.exe in there. Run that and it'll bring you to the installation center where you can choose to install a new instance and do a bunch of other things. It's a wizard type interface so just read the instructions on each page and you should be able to provide the relevant info where needed to successfully complete the installation

Comment: I know how to manually install SQL Server using that process, however I want to use the chef recipe to do it automatically.

Comment: use the right product key and you'll get the right edition installed. Cookbook sample shows where to provide product key. SQL Server doesn't have separate base installers for different server editions anymore. Only Express continues to have its own install package.