# Can Chef windows_package install without copying the package file?

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I'm trying to install SQL server with Chef, [as described here in Option 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32552014/1448813). So I mounted the iso, started the script, and Chef copied the setup.exe to c:\chef\cache, as it does with .msi packages. How do I run the setup directly from the mounted disc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 there is talking about writing your own cookbook code so the answer is the somewhat unhelpful "write recipe to do that thing you said". If tell Chef to run D:\setup.exe or whatever, then it will do that.